# Validate AngularJS HTML snippet with a well typed controller using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Help appreciated anyone!

We are currently using a mixture of AngularJS and TypeScript in our project. It's going well, and virtually all of the Javascript is well typed with only a few abstracted exceptions.

Our remaining problem are the views... the HTML files. Should any scope variables have a name or type change, or get removed... VS won't pick this up at compile time.  What generally happens is at run-time, the views referencing the changed scope variables simply show a blank at that point.  This is a real pain, and across a large team (and large project) this represents some risk we could do with out.

Does anyone know of any tricks etc. to ensure that the HTML content in an AngularJS application marries up correctly with the controllers and scope in the Javascript of the project - where breakages are brought to the developers attention at design time?

----- edit --------------------------------------------------

For example (in the html file),

```
<div ng-show="mc.showADiv()"></div>
```

Where (in the type-script file),

mc = controller written as a type-script class and registered

showADiv() = class method that returns a boolean value

To put it simple... should a developer change the name or signature of type-script method "showADiv", the application will still build and not report any errors.  When you run the application, you will get a run time error.  So the html technically is not as well typed as I would like.

You can extrapolate this example to anything "code like" in the angular html file... if you make a typo, your screwed until someone picks it up at run time.

----- eof edit --------------------------------------------------

Many thanks.

Comment: The question seems pretty vague. What do you mean by ' AngularJS application marries up correctly with the controllers and scope in the Javascript of the project'? If possible provide a sample code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the response (sorry for the late reply)... I don't have a specific example on me at the moment, so I have tried to explain further what I mean with this question... does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution here ?